# Why my genetic algorithm doesn't converge?

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

At first I create a script giving the name multi_002
After I create the function that includes the equation
The script calls the function and reads the array 'a'.
Each array include one equation `a(i) = x - i`
I want to minimize its equation of the 4 lines array 'a'.
I suspect that something doesn't work right. I notice that

[image]

Optimtool works but f1,f2,f3,f4 doesn't go to zero. With another words
there isn't convergence. 
    FitnessFunction = @array_002;
    numberOfVariables = 1;
    [x,fval] = gamultiobj(FitnessFunction,numberOfVariables);

```
function [a,y,c]= array_002(x)
  size = 4; n = 4;
  y = zeros(size,1);
  c = zeros(size,1); 
 for i = 1:n 
   y(i) = x;
   c(i) = i;
   a = y - c;
 end
```

Why my genetic algorithm doesn't converge? Is there any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: because genetic algorithms are based on randomness. They are not ensured to converge.

Comment: this seems like a question for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence

Comment: Once again, looking for a minimum to a function that doesn't have a minimum would cause any algorithm to diverge